# CollapsingToolbarLayout scroll not work after setAppearanceLightStatusBars on API 26

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, windowinsets

I create simple `ScrollingActivity` (which created by new Android template) it's working fine while scrolling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApplication.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.TestApplication.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

However, after I use `setAppearanceLightStatusBars` in `addOnOffsetChangedListener`, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` not work well anymore

```
binding.appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appbarLayout, verticalOffset: Int ->
    val seekPosition = -verticalOffset / appbarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()

    val isLightStatusBar = seekPosition > 0.5
    if (isLightStatusBar != WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars) {
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(
            window, window.decorView
        ).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = isLightStatusBar
    }
}
```

[image]

This problem is only happen on Android 26 (or maybe lower), it's not happens with newer Android version.
Beside that, the issue will not happen if I use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` to set light statusbar (but `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` deprecated)

Comment: Can you show me what theme did you used for app ?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhKhoa I'm using the default AppTheme NoActionBar without any modifications, the pictures above are from a brand new demo app

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround as I couldn't find any solution

After checking the code, currently
`WindowInsetsControllerCompat#isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true`

will do thoes things on Android < 30

```
add flag SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
remove flag FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
add flag FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
```

And I figure out that the scroll problem in collapsing toolbar only happens when we combine the 1st flag to 2nd or 3rd flag.

Also, its weird that problem is not happens on Android 29, but it happens on 26,27,28

Finally, I end up with using only `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` for API < 30 and keep using `WindowInsetsControllerCompat` for API >= 30